# Less: Dividing variables?

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to divide two variables in Less?
Like `@varA = @varB / @varC;`?

I already tried it with escaping, but the output is not what I need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All operations should be placed within parentheses

```
@varB = 1;
@varC = 2;
@varA = (@varB / @varC); /* @varA == 0.5 */
```

Comment: If you are worrying about the unit, you could as @bookcasey suggests multiply by 1px, or have the variables include unit. Any color, number or other variable can be operated on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
@var1: 100;
@var2: 10;
@var3: @var1 / @var2;

h1 {
  font-size: @var3*1px;
}
```